# DMARC Validates DKIM failed

Tags: gmail, dkim, dmarc

DMARC validates DKIM result as failed :(

When im sending mails to GMAIL my DMARC report always returns the respond from the screenshot.

I have already tried multiple validation tests to check my SPF and DKIM i cant see the problem.

When im sending to Microsoft mails, i get a PASSED ... 4

Anyone have an idea ?

DMARC RESULT

[image]

MAIL TEST RESULT

[image]

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! Please don't post text as images, instead copy-paste (and format as quote/code if needed) the text inside your post.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like your DKIM is failing, keep in mind a lot of companies use there own DKIM Validators and some might have bugs in it, where you pass on one, you might fail on another. A lot of time the failures are based around the headers that are signed and if you have duplicate signed headers the DKIM Validator's sometimes don't work correctly. Based on those results that you displayed, it's really hard to tell you what's wrong. If you want to run another test use `mailtest@unlocktheinbox.com` they use 4 different independent DKIM validators in their results. It might give you a better clue as to what's happening.

Thanks for linking the report..

1. Your DMARC is violating [RFC 7489](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7489) Standard on Page 28.

> For example, if a DMARC policy query for "blue.example.com" contained
> "rua=mailto:reports@red.example.net", the host extracted from the
> latter ("red.example.net") does not match "blue.example.com", so this
> procedure is enacted.  A TXT query for
> "blue.example.com._report._dmarc.red.example.net" is issued.  If a
> single reply comes back containing a tag of "v=DMARC1", then the
> relationship between the two is confirmed.  Moreover,
> "red.example.net" has the opportunity to override the report
> destination requested by "blue.example.com" if needed.

So you need add the record below to DNS of architection.net with a value of `v=DMARC1`

```
hasserispizzaria.dk._report_dmarc.architection.net
```

2. You don't have an SSL Certificate on your Mail Server - You should get one, you can find them for under $15.
3. I don't see anything wrong with your DKIM, I don't see anything in your headers that would indicate why it will fail GMAIL? When you send an email to a GMAIL account that you own, does it say DKIM is failing? When you look at the headers from a GMAIL account.

Comment: Hi ... Have done the test, and here is the result link... hopefully someone can see something wrong here that could explain the problem
[link](http://hasserispizzaria.dk/Email_Result.pdf)

Answer (score 0):

If the answer provided by Henry doesn't work, then it could be a DNS record problem. My server has DirectAdmin and if I enter the record without " " surrounding the record some online tools do and some don't recognize. With " " they always work. Maybe this could (also) be a part of the problem. Also backslashing the parameters sometimes work (experienced that on 2 servers, one with DA and one with cPanel, wouldn't work fully without it on DA).